# Using Three.js with Laravel - Require is not defined

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, three.js

I'm in the process of converting my project over to Laravel, and this uses the Three.js library. I followed their [Import via Modules](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Import-via-modules) documentation, but get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at stl:71`, so I assume it isn't being loaded correctly.

I did the following...

- Ran "npm install three" in my Laravel root directory
- Ran "npm run dev"
- Put the following code snippet in the script section of my blade template

  ```
  var THREE = require('three');

  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  scene.add( cube );

  camera.position.z = 5;

  function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );

      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

      renderer.render( scene, camera );
  }

  animate();
  ```

I'm still getting familiar with using Laravel and NPM, where I think I may need to import the library somewhere before using it. The ThreeJS documentation doesn't make any mention of this though (when using the NPM module) so I am confused.

Pretty sure I can import it in the `resources\app.js` for global access, but only need to use it on certain pages. Being the case, I would prefer to figure out why `var THREE = require('three');` isn't working.

Comment: `Put the following code snippet in my blade template` 

you mean with `<script>` tag right?

Comment: @MarufAlom It's in script tags, the code blocks on Stack Overflow removed them for some reason (can still see them in Edit but not on save).

Comment: replace require to import. 
`import THREE from 'three'`

Comment: @MarufAlom I got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` when switching it to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file under `public/js/three.js` and put your codes in there.

Then in your blade file add this in script section

`<script src="/js/three.js" type="module"></script>`

Hope it might work

Another way would be changing your webpack config file to:

*webpack.mix.js*

```js
mix.webpackConfig({
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js?$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: mix.config.babel()
      }]
    }]
  }
});
```

Comment: I was avoiding this method as I wanted to keep the modules loaded via NPM packages, but it seems like this is likely my best route at the moment. Probably just overlooking something simple with the NPM method, but I will leave that for another day.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a look at [Three.js documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation)
2. Important note:

> Because the library relies on ES modules, any script that references it must use type="module"

...Like:

```
<script type="module">
```

3. Then you can do stuff like:

```
import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js';
```

4. Read more [about Javascript modules here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)